# How to split Japanese text?

Tags: text, stanford-nlp, opennlp, cjk, kuromoji

What is the best way of splitting Japanese text using Java?
For Example, for the below text:

```
こんにちは。私の名前はオバマです。私はアメリカに行く。
```

I need the following output:

```
こんにちは
私の名前はオバマです
私はアメリカに行く
```

Is it possible using Kuromoji?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use java.text.BreakIterator.

```
String TEXT = "こんにちは。私の名前はオバマです。私はアメリカに行く。";
BreakIterator boundary = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.JAPAN);
boundary.setText(TEXT);
int start = boundary.first();
for (int end = boundary.next();
     end != BreakIterator.DONE;
     start = end, end = boundary.next()) {
     System.out.println(TEXT.substring(start, end));
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
こんにちは。
私の名前はオバマです。
私はアメリカに行く。
```

You cannot use Kuromoji to look for Japanese sentence boundaries. It can split a sentence into words.

Comment: To fit his desired out, you should also use strip() on the 。's.

Comment: This solution is not working for text "速い茶色のキツネは怠惰な犬を飛び越えます"