# Splitting Japanese text into words in java using BreakIterator

Tags: java, locale, cjk, breakiterator

We are trying to break Japanese sentences into words using BreakIterator by following the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52145954/how-to-split-japanese-text). This code is working fine only for the text which is given in the question and when we try giving a different text e.g "速い茶色のキツネは怠惰な犬を飛び越えます" it is unable to break the words.

What could be the issue?

Comment: The mentioned solution splits on `。`.  It splits sentences. Why did you assume it would split the sentenxce with no periods into words? Also, what exactly is a *word* here?

Comment: @Fureeish are you sure that it uses punctations to break the text into sentences and it won't work when the provided text doesn't have any punctuation?

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers yes, I am quite sure.

Answer (score 1):

`BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.JAPAN)` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52145954/how-to-split-japanese-text) breaks a Japanese script into *sentences*, rather than *words*. Usually, the Japanese language is written without punctuation to separate words.

You have to use a morphological analyzer to break a sentence into words. For example, you can use a [Java port of TinySegmenter](https://github.com/toastkidjp/word_cloud/tree/master/src/main/java/jp/toastkid/libs/tinysegmenter).

```java
import java.util.List;
import jp.toastkid.libs.tinysegmenter.TinySegmenter;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      TinySegmenter ts = TinySegmenter.getInstance();
      List<String> list = ts.segment("速い茶色のキツネは怠惰な犬を飛び越えます。");
      System.out.println(String.join(" | ", list));
      // You will get "速い | 茶色 | の | キツネ | は | 怠惰 | な | 犬 | を | 飛び越え | ます"
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `怠惰な` a single word? And what about `飛び越えます`? My knowledge is very limited, but `ます` doesn't *feel* like it qualifies for an independent word. Could you please elaborate on that, perhaps strictly from the japanese language point of view?

Comment: Based on the knowledge from Japanese junior high program: "怠惰な" is a single word, conjugation of a 形容動詞 (adjectival noun) "怠惰だ". "ます" is a 助動詞 in Japanese language, see: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E_(%E5%9B%BD%E6%96%87%E6%B3%95)

Comment: So if `怠惰な` is a single word, then the library you linked incorrectly treats it as two separate words, doesn't it?

Comment: @Fureeish You're exactly right. But when an adjectival noun finishes with "だ", it can't be determined an adjectival noun or noun + 助動詞 only by appearance. For example, another morphological analyzer MeCab (the most widely used morphological analyzer for Japanese) also identifies "怠惰だ" as a noun + 助動詞. see: http://www4414uj.sakura.ne.jp/Yasanichi1/unicheck/

I have taught some ways to distinguish them in junior high (e.g. it even makes sense when adding some adverb before the word), but these methods need natural-language semantic analysis.

Comment: Makes sense. Many thanks for in depth explanation!